# how to send mail to a mailing list with java?

Tags: java, email, unix

I want to send a mail to a mailing list every period of time (like every 40min or hour) with java on a unix server.
I'd like any code or tutorial to be able to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending a mail to a mailing list does not differ from sending a regular mail. The simplest way is to use [commons-email](http://commons.apache.org/email/). Check its examples.

Answer (score 0):

JavaMail is the usual approach for this.  You will need a SMTP-server for JavaMail to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not necessary to USE SMTP - java mail enough
Simple example

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class MailSender {
        private static String host = "";
        private static String user = "";
        private static String password = "";
        private static int port = 465;
        private static String from = "";
        private static String to = "";

        private static String auth = "true";
        private static String debug = "false";
        private static String socket_factory = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
        private static String subject = "";
        private static String text = "";

        /**
         * Constructor. Fields - parameters for send mail.
         *  
         * @param host - mail server.
         * @param user - user
         * @param password - login
         * @param port - port
         * @param from - mail from address
         * @param to - mail to address
         * @param subject - subject
         * @param text - text of mail
         */
        public MailSender(String host, String user, String password, int port,
                        String from, String to, String subject, String text) {

                if (!host.isEmpty())
                        setHost(host);
                if (!user.isEmpty())
                        setUser(user);
                if (!password.isEmpty())
                        setPassword(password);
                if (port == 0)
                        setPort(port);
                if (!from.isEmpty())
                        setFrom(from);
                if (!to.isEmpty())
                        setTo(to);
                if (!subject.isEmpty())
                        setSubject(subject);
                if (!text.isEmpty())
                        setText(text);
        }

        /**
         * Send mail with parameters from constructor.
         */

        public void send() {
                // Use Properties object to set environment properties
                Properties props = new Properties();

                props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
                props.put("mail.smtp.host", getHost());
                props.put("mail.smtp.port", getPort());
                props.put("mail.smtp.user", getUser());

                props.put("mail.smtp.auth", getAuth());
                props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");//for gmail?
                props.put("mail.smtp.debug", getDebug());

                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", getPort());
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");//for gmail?
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

                try {

                        // Obtain the default mail session
                        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
                        session.setDebug(new Boolean(getDebug()));

                        // Construct the mail message
                        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                        message.setText(getText());
                        message.setSubject(getSubject());
                        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(getFrom()));
                        message
                                        .addRecipient(RecipientType.TO,
                                                        new InternetAddress(getTo()));
                        message.saveChanges();

                        // Use Transport to deliver the message
                        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
                        transport.connect(getHost(), getUser(), getPassword());
                        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
                        transport.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }

        public static String getHost() {
                return host;
        }

        public static void setHost(String host) {
                MailSender.host = host;
        }

        public static String getUser() {
                return user;
        }

        public static void setUser(String user) {
                MailSender.user = user;
        }

        public static String getPassword() {
                return password;
        }

        public static void setPassword(String password) {
                MailSender.password = password;
        }

        public static int getPort() {
                return port;
        }

        public static void setPort(int port) {
                MailSender.port = port;
        }

        public static String getFrom() {
                return from;
        }

        public static void setFrom(String from) {
                MailSender.from = from;
        }

        public static String getTo() {
                return to;
        }

        public static void setTo(String to) {
                MailSender.to = to;
        }

        public static String getAuth() {
                return auth;
        }

        public static void setAuth(String auth) {
                MailSender.auth = auth;
        }

        public static String getDebug() {
                return debug;
        }

        public static void setDebug(String debug) {
                MailSender.debug = debug;
        }

        public static String getSocket_factory() {
                return socket_factory;
        }

        public static void setSocket_factory(String socketFactory) {
                socket_factory = socketFactory;
        }

        public static String getSubject() {
                return subject;
        }

        public static void setSubject(String subject) {
                MailSender.subject = subject;
        }

        public static String getText() {
                return text;
        }

        public static void setText(String text) {
                MailSender.text = text;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
String[] mailToId = {
    "abc@mail.com",
    "abc22@mail.com",
    "abc33@mail.com"
};
for (int i = 0; i < mailToId.length; i++) {
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(mailToId[i]));;
}
```

In your java class you can use array of mail address and one by one mail address can call using for loop.

Within the for loop you can call

`message.addRecipient();`

method with array name.

look at the above example: